# Extreme points of unit ball in $C(X)$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $C(X)$ be the space of continuos functions in sup-norm.

I read in [Douglas' *Banach algebra techniques in operator theory*](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-0-387-98377-6) that the followings are equivalent:

> 1)$f\in C(X)$ is an extreme point of the unit ball;

and

> 2)$|f(x)|=1$ for all $x\in X$.

It is easy to show that 2) implies 1). However, I am unable to show the converse.

I could show that $f$ is extreme implies $\|f\|=1$ but this is far from what we need.

My guess: if 2) is false. We try to construct a nonnegative function $r$ on $X$ which is strictly positive when $|f(x)|\neq 1$ and meanwhile \begin{equation}
|(1+r)f|\le 1
\end{equation}on $X$.  Then we can decompose  \begin{equation}
f=\frac{1}{2}(1+r)f+\frac{1}{2}(1-r)f.
\end{equation} 
If $|f|$ is bounded away from $0$, then $r=-1+1/|f|$ would be a good choice, but I cannot rule out the case when $f$ vanishes at certain points.

Can somebody help? Thanks!

Also a related problem, Douglas then says these extreme points of the unit ball spans the entire $C(X)$. Can somebody also give a hint on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose $\varepsilon=|f(t_0)|<1$ for some $t_0$. By continuity there exists $V\ni t_0$, open, with  $|f(t)-f (t_0)|<(1-\varepsilon)/2$ for all $t\in V$. Now let $g$ be a continuous function, supported on $V$, such that $g(t_0)=(1-\varepsilon)/2$ and $|g|\leq(1-\varepsilon)/2$.

Then $|f\pm g|\leq1$, and $f=\frac12(f+g)+\frac12(f-g)$, so $f$ is not extreme.

**Edit:** regarding your second question, it is something you already know. $C(X)$ is a unital C$^*$-algebra, so any element is a linear combination of four unitaries, by the usual trick of writing a complex number $a+ib$ with $|a+ib|\leq 1$ as 
$$
\begin{align}
a+ib=&\frac12\left([a+i(1-a^2)^{1/2}]+[a-i(1-a^2)^{1/2}]\right)\\
&+\frac{i}2\left([b+i(1-b^2)^{1/2}]+[b-i(1-b^2)^{1/2}]\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: «The usual trick»? I consider myself lucky that I had never seen that identity before! :-)

Comment: Hi, it's been a long time since you answered this, but I want to ask: for element in the unit ball $B_{C(X)}$, do we have a way to write it as convex combination of extreme points?

Comment: Not sure. I would imagine the answer is "no", but I don't have an argument. I'll try to think about it.

Answer (score 12):

You are quite close: don't look at $(1\pm r)f$, look at $f\pm r$ instead.

There is $\varepsilon \gt 0$ such that the set $U = \{x : \lvert f(x)\rvert \lt 1-\varepsilon\}$ is non-empty. Let $u \in U$ be arbitrary. Urysohn's lemma gives a function $g$ such that $g(u) = 1$ and $g|_{U^c} \equiv 0$. Take $r = \varepsilon g$. Then $f = \frac{1}{2}(f+r) + \frac{1}{2}(f-r)$ shows that $f$ is not extremal because $\lvert f(x) \pm r(x)\rvert \leq 1$ for all $x$.