# Are dual spaces with unconditional bases weakly sequentially complete?

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-lattices

It is well known that a [weakly sequentially complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#Weak_convergences_of_sequences) Banach space with an unconditional basis is isomorphic to a conjugate space.
Is the converse to this statement true?

> If a Banach space is a conjugate space and has an unconditional basis, must it be weakly sequentially complete?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. More generally this holds for separable Banach lattices that are dual spaces (spaces with unconditional bases are Banach lattices with the positive cone consisting of vectors having non-negative coefficients with respect to a given unconditional basis).

Indeed, we have the following generalisation of a theorem of James (This is Theorem 1.4.c in the second volume of Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri):

> Let $X$ be a Banach lattice. Then $X$ is weakly sequentially complete if and only if it does not contain subspaces isomorphic to $c_0$.

Now, a separable dual cannot contain subspaces isomorphic to $c_0$ as every such subspace would be complemented ([Sobczyk's theorem](http://matematicas.unex.es/~fcabello/files/printable/21.pdf)) and this would contradict [the Phillips-Sobczyk theorem](http://matematicas.unex.es/~fcabello/files/printable/21.pdf). (You will find more details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249431/is-the-complex-banach-space-c0-1-dual-to-any-banach-space/1252540#1252540).)